# function is not called correctly in bash

Tags: bash

I have this bash code that checks if the OS is Linux or Mac, and I use the function isWhat to be invoked from other functions.

```
function isWhat 
{
  if [ `uname` == $1 ];
  then
    return 1
  else
    return 0  
  fi
}

function isLinux 
{
    return isWhat("Linux")
}

function isMac
{
    return isWhat("Darwin")
}
```

However, I got these errors:

```
/functions.sh: line 13: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/functions.sh: line 13: `    return isWhat("Linux")'
runme.sh: line 7: isMac: command not found
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: Also, don't use the `function` keyword at all; it makes your script incompatible with POSIX sh for no good reason. `isWhat() {` is enough to start a function, and using that form retains compatibility with pure POSIX shells.

Comment: You've got other bugs in here too, by the way -- you're missing quotes around expansions (that one's a "real" bug, even if your only target is bash), and `==` isn't guaranteed to work inside `[ ]` by the POSIX standard (the standardized string comparison operator is `=`, not `==`). Try running through http://shellcheck.net/ for an automated check for the quoting errors.

Comment: ...and as a matter of practice, if you're writing something to be sourced in as an include file and using bash-only syntax, name it `.bash`, not `.sh`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the working code after fixing some bugs.

```
function isWhat 
{
  if [ "`uname`" = $1 ];
  then
    echo 1
  else
    echo 0  
  fi
}

function isLinux 
{
    isWhat "Linux"
}

function isMac
{
    isWhat "Darwin"
}
```

The usage is (assuming the previous functions are in abc.sh)

```
source abc.sh
echo $(isMac)
if [ $(isMac) == 1 ];
then
    echo "A"
fi
```

I'm not sure exactly why, but I had to add `function` to make the code work anyway, I use Mac OS X 10.11.1.

Comment: fwiw, the way you had it before with returns, if you swapped the 0/1 you could simply use `if isLinux; then ... fi`.

Answer (score 5):

That's not how you call functions in `bash`.  They work just like other shell commands, i.e.:

```
function isLinux 
{
    isWhat "Linux"
}
```

Also, the `return` is redundant the function will return the exit status of the last command run. If you wanted to be explicit, you'd write it like:

```
function isLinux 
{
    isWhat "Linux"
    return $?
}
```

Comment: If we're pointing folks towards best practices, I'd tend to suggest POSIX-compliant function call syntax as well (`isLinux() {` with no `function`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point.  OP did say `bash` but since the point of this is to detect platform, making it more cross platform makes a lot of sense, so I'd tend to agree.

Answer (score -1):

You're calling the bash functions incorrectly.

e.g.

```
return isWhat("Linux")
```

Should be

```
return isWhat "Linux"
```

etc

Comment: ...and there's no point to the `return`; just making it `isWhat "Linux"` will pass the return value from the `isWhat` function through to the caller.

Comment: moreover, the documentation for `return` defines it to take an integer, not a command to call at all.